# Hosting emoji domains quandary

Tags: iis, unicode, 400

I am trying to make my IIS8.5 to process IDN domains, including the domains with emoji characters. Since the application runs **dynamic hostnames** I bind by IP and protocol only.  The IIS8.5 does fine job to do IDN and Punycode reconstruction but only for the Unicode characters that are part of the Windows Unicode binary table, which I think older then Unicode 6.0. In case a domain has some kind of character from let say MAC Unicode binary table then the hostnames could not be reconstructed and the server throws 400: The request hostname is invalid. I played with all imaginable configuration of IIS and all possible setting of mashine.config but it did not bring me any success.

The key problem that since the IIS binging does not get engaged then there is no application event fires and I cannot intervene bad requests with my code and deal with consequences of wrong characters. So, I have a few questions to ask, answer to any of them I think will address my problem?

1)  Is any ways to bind IIS site with Unicode characters and no hostname which would be outside of Windows Unicode table? Is any way to alter Windows Unicode table?

2)  I do not mind to implement a Global IIS module to deal with the problem via my own code but what would require to rise a pre-binging event. Does IIS expose any pre-binging events?

3)  Is any other way to sniff HTTP traffic over IP/PORT using .Net code witch would not include IIS?

Thanks for your thoughts.